# Github contribution grid snake is showing wrong

Tags: github-actions, output, readme

I want to show [this cute snake](https://github.com/Platane/snk) in my Github.

Referenced [this site](https://dev.to/mishmanners/how-to-enable-github-actions-on-your-profile-readme-for-a-contribution-graph-4l66) and wrote this in [MY_GITHUB_USERNAME]/.github/workflows/main.yml using base branch 'main'.

```
name: Generate Snake

on:
  schedule:
      # every 6 hours
    - cron: "0 */6 * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: Platane/snk@master
        id: snake-gif
        with:
          github_user_name: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          # these next 2 lines generate the files on a branch called "output". This keeps the main branch from cluttering up.
          gif_out_path: dist/github-contribution-grid-snake.gif
          svg_out_path: dist/github-contribution-grid-snake.svg

      - run: git status

      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: main
          force: true

      - uses: crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages@v2.1.3
        with:
          # the output branch we mentioned above
          target_branch: output
          build_dir: dist
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Build is success, then switch 'output' branch and when click github-contribution-grid-snake.gif, it [shows weird](https://github.com/yeslee-v/yeslee-v/blob/output/github-contribution-grid-snake.gif).

What's wrong and How can i do?

reference a lot of other blogs and try..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend following the official instructions from the [snk github repository](https://github.com/Platane/snk?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) because other sources on the internet can be outdated. You can also find sample workflows [in their `.github` folder](https://github.com/Platane/snk/tree/main/.github/workflows).

Here is correct workflow file which I tested myself. It uses v3 of snk instead of v2 like you were using. Place it in the `.github/workflows` folder on your main branch:

```
name: Snake generator

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 * * * *" #  run every hour

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create snake
        uses: Platane/snk@v3
        with:
          # github user name to read the contribution graph from (**required**)
          # using action context var `github.repository_owner` or specified user
          github_user_name: ${{ github.repository_owner }}

          # list of files to generate.
          # one file per line. Each output can be customized with options as query string.
          #
          #  supported options:
          #  - palette:     A preset of color, one of [github, github-dark, github-light]
          #  - color_snake: Color of the snake
          #  - color_dots:  Coma separated list of dots color.
          #                 The first one is 0 contribution, then it goes from the low contribution to the highest.
          #                 Exactly 5 colors are expected.
          outputs: |
            dist/github-snake.svg
            dist/github-snake-dark.svg?palette=github-dark
            dist/ocean.gif?color_snake=orange&color_dots=#bfd6f6,#8dbdff,#64a1f4,#4b91f1,#3c7dd9


      - name: push github-contribution-grid-snake.svg to the output branch
        uses: crazy-max/ghaction-github-pages@v3.1.0
        with:
          target_branch: output
          build_dir: dist
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The files will be generated on the `snake-output` branch. My gif for example looks like this:

[image]

Comment: OMG Thanks a lot!!! I miss that version :)